# Prove by induction that $x^n-y^n$ is divisble by $x-y$ for $ n \ge 1 $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction

I'm new to inductive proofs so I need some commentary on my proof since the book only gives a hint in the back. In "Discrete Mathematics with Applications" by Epp Third Edition in section 4.3 problem 13 states

> For any integer $ n \ge 1,  x^n - y^n$ is divisible by $(x - y)$ 
>   where x and y are any integers with $ x \ne y $

My Proof is as follows.

let $ Q(n) = x^n - y^n $

Then the base case is

$ Q(1) = x^1 - y^1 $

Now

$ Q(n + 1) = x^{n+1} - y^{n+1} = (x^n + y^n)(x-y)$

So now we can see $(x-y)$ is a factor and in turn divisible by $(x-y)$. I have just one hesitation. I didn't substitute from the inductive hypotheses. In every other inductive proof I've done this was a necessary step. My intuition on induction tells me that I have basically set up all of the dominoes but failed to knock down the first one (the substitution). Is this necessary for a valid proof or does this hold?

Comment: Your last equality is false. $(x^n+y^n)(x-y)=x^{n+1}+xy^n-x^ny-y^{n+1}$

Comment: In your base case, you need to take out "$= 1 - 1 = 0 = 8(0)$". Your TA will take out partial credits when he sees it.

Comment: @scaaahu I'm not in school. I just do math because I want to understand Donald Knuth. But just out of curiosity why would they do that? Edit: Wait no. I see it.

Comment: What do you mean by "why would they do that?" do what?

Comment: @scaaahu Why would they mark me off. But never mind I see the error now.

Comment: Still wrong. Take out "$ = 1 -1 = 0$". How did you get the idea $x = y = 1$? They are variables.

Comment: @scaaahu I though that they were be taking to 0 exponent but then how would that help with being divisible by (x-y) I have no idea. I must need sleep.

Comment: Upvoted because at least you get the base case correct. Go to bed and get to the rest of it tomorrow. You can't learn everything in one day.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your factorisation is incorrect. Use $x^{n+1}-y^{n+1}=x(x^n-y^n)+y^n(x-y)$.

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly the substitution happens inside the term $ x(x^n - y^n) $ which would be $x(x-y) + y^n(x-y)$ ? Then I could proceed to factor or am I missing a factoring technique in my tool belt?

Comment: You do indeed use the inductive step to verify $x-y|x^n-y^n$, although the expression you wrote after that isn't right.

Answer (score 3):

***Non-Inductive Proof (or so I thought).***

---

*Proof*: Suppose there exists $z$ such that $$x^n-y^n = z(x-y).$$ This would imply that $z=\dfrac{x^n-y^n}{x-y}$. Now, here comes the trick: $$\frac{x^n-y^n}{x-y} = \frac{x^{n-1}(x-y)+yx^{n-1}-y^n}{x-y}=x^{n-1}+y\left(\frac{x^{n-1}-y^{n-1}}{x-y}\right).$$ Continuing in the same way, it follows that $$x^{n-1}+y\left(\frac{x^{n-1}-y^{n-1}}{x-y}\right)=x^{n-1}+yx^{n-2}+y\left(\frac{x^{n-2}-y^{n-2}}{x-y}\right)=\cdots$$ to which a pattern can be noticed, namely, $$z=\sum_{k=1}^nx^{n-k}y^{k-1}\tag*{$\bigcirc$}$$

---

I decided to not do an inductive proof in order to  explore a different way of tackling this problem :)

**Edit:** Turns out, it *is* an inductive proof, but it just skips the base case and is differently worded than usual. Credit to @J.G. who pointed that out :)

Comment: That's still induction.

Comment: @J.G. what do you mean? I have not used a base case, inductive hypothesis, or an inductive step. I just cleverly rewrote the numerator.

Comment: "It terminates like this" is your inductive hypothesis.

Comment: @J.G. hah... I didn't realise. Looks like it *is* an inductive proof. Is there a way of proving the assertion with-out the use of induction, do you know?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm sure someone would suggest "use the factor theorem", but the proof of that probably requires induction on the degree of polynomials. My favourite on-SE discussion of what constitutes induction is https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1359020

Comment: @J.G. thank you for showing me that post in the link. It is very interesting. I wonder if there are any other assertions that cannot be proven without induction :)

Answer (score 2):

Following the suggestion by J.G., for the induction step we assume true that

- $Q(n) = x^{n} - y^{n} = p_{n-1}(x)\cdot (x-y)$

were $p_{n-1}(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ then

- $Q(n+1) = x^{n+1} - y^{n+1} = x\cdot(x^n-y^n)+y^n(x-y)=x\cdot\,\color{red}{p_{n-1}(x)\cdot(x-y)}+y^n(x-y)=p_n(x)\cdot(x-y)$

Comment: I don't quite follow the notation you are using. Epp simply uses the variable r when using the inductive hypotheses for divisibility. Would this also be valid if? so then I think I proved it successfully on paper just before I logged on today. $ xr(x-y) + y^n(x-y) = (xr+y^n)(x-y) $

Comment: Also Epp states that r is an integer. Sorry.

Comment: @PossiblyDakota $p_{n-1}(x)$ and $p_n(x)$ are just polynomials of degree $n−1$ and $n$ in $x$ and $y$ thus they can be also indicated as some integer $r_1$ and $r_2$. It is a minor issue in the proof.